# Rewrite pages with a certain url to another htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What I need to do it rewrite a url from one thing to another eg:

```
http://www.domain.com/page_one/blah //to
http://www.domain.com/page_two/blah
```

I've tried a few script I've found around the internet but I'm terrible with `.htaccess` and can never understand or get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change **only** this specific url, use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page_one/blah?$ http://www.domain.com/page_two/bla [L]
```

If you want to change the url for every file into the "page_one"-folder, this will help you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page_one/([^/]+)$ http://www.domain.com/page_two/$1 [L]
```

The `RewriteEngine On` activates the RewriteEnigine, so that you are able to use RewriteRules.
The `([^/]+)` in the second solution means "every file, but no folders (the slash is excluded)". This is stored in `$1` and used to create the new url.

**Edit**
`[L]` stops the script from using the other rules (if you have some)